# Dynamically replacing DIV's inner text in GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm looking for the possibilities that `GWT`, `SmartGWT`, offers in terms of dynamically changing the inner HTML text of an element.

**Let go though an example :**

I have some lorem ipsum text in a `DIV` element as it follows :

```html
<div id="text">
    Lorem <span style="background-color:red">ipsum </span>
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Duis convallis iaculis 
    <span style="background-color:red">ipsum </span>
    magna sagittis vel. Lorem
    <span style="background-color:red">ipsum </span> dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

**Desired functionality :**

I want the user to be allowed to decide at *runtime* what text is "marked" (red colored). This impact in two things :

- Being able to *remove* an span element, thus replacing

```html
<span style="background-color:red">ipsum </span>
```

by

```
ipsum
```

- Being able to *add* an span element (by doing the opposite)

Once the user has selected the text he wants to "mark", I use something like

```java
RootPanel.get("text").getElement().
setInnerHTML("html content with some new spans tags");
```

to update the HTML code with the new *selection* (to achieve that I have some GWT classed that keeps track of the *marked* text).

This seems to be a *little brutal* for me because I'm in a situation that I often update the inner HTML code.

Is there any way using GWT (working closely with the DOM) or SmartGWT, to achieve that in a less *violent* way ?

Comment: it seems brutal for me, because to change 1% of the html code, you have to change all of it. It makes the browser do unnecessary rendering calculations.

Comment: Yes, but you can edit only the parts that you need. So, you only edit this 1% that you want. RootPanel.get("the_div_you_want")

Comment: I may be wrong, but can't you surround the part you want with a <div id="x"></div> ? I think it possible to surround everything with a div.what I say is, try to give an id to the part you want. you can do this with a div, or in any other way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the DOM of your page you can call `Document.get()`, which has a convenience method for finding an element by it's id `Document.get().getElementById("test");`

Of course, you should keep a reference to this element so as not to have to search through the DOM everytime you want to access it, because this is brutal.

```
private Element testDiv = Document.get().getElementById("test");
...

testDiv.setInnerHTML("Some html");
...
testDiv.setInnerHTML("Some other html");
```

But once you have a reference to this element, calling setInnerHTML is the most efficient way to do what you want. I'm not sure why you think this is brutal. This is probably even more efficient than when you call a method on a widget to change it's content, like `setText(" ...")` on a `TextBox` for example, because these methods usually check the value passed as parameter for security.

Security could also be a concern for you, depending on what the user can do. But usually if a user can modify the HTML in your page that's a concern. You might want to look at GWT's [SafeHTML](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml) feature.

If you're looking for RichText components, you can look at [GWT's RichTextArea](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText) for example. But this type of component is usually not well supported by all browsers and will take more resources than what you're doing already so I don't recommend it.

Comment: the GWT's RichTextArea is a good example of the functionality I'm trying to achieve. My DIV is like a "CanEdit" area of the application. I've explained why I think this is brutal in the comments of my question

Comment: Everytime you see something changing on a web page, the DOM of the page is modified. There's no way around it, but modern browser are pretty good about rendering it. Changing the innerHTML of one div should cause no problem, even if you do it quite a lot. Widgets like the RichTextArea eventually end up calling setInnerHTML on a div too, but they do a lot more work before that so if you only want to set spans around some text your solution will be more efficient

Comment: The big question that I ask myself is : *What is the best way* ? 1. Keeps on GWT classes the track of span selections, and fire setInnerHTML everytime there is a change. Or, 2. Do all the modifications at the DOM level, modifying only affected elements (to do that, I have to surround even non *marked* text by spans).

Comment: It depends on your problem. Can the text inside the div change ? Can the user select any part of it ? Can the user select as many parts as he wants or just one, or two. Depending on these constraints, you could separate your text in smaller divs and spans and only change the content of the relevant ones. In my opinion, if your div contains simple HTML (only text and spans) and isn't too big, just change all of it's innertHTML all the time.

Comment: The text can't change, the user can select as many parts as he wants (exactly as RichTextArea can), he can select any part. I can have more than 300 *marked* text in a 500 words text. I will keep in mind all your advises.